# Filtering a column for only Numerical values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where a column is named as USER_ID. Ideally USER_ID should be of numerical No but the data that is coming from source is having typically some bad records which i want to discard in my final dataframe. For example the values in the column are like below

DF

| USER_ID |
| --- |
| 23456 |
| 1236 |
| NO_NULL |
| FBA56X%^ |

and the final dataframe should be

DF1

| USER_ID |
| --- |
| 23456 |
| 1236 |

The code i am using to clean it is as below

```
DF1 = DF[np.isfinite(pd.to_numeric(DF.USER_ID,errors='coerce))]
```

But it seems this code is not acting properly. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The code is "not acting properly" how?

Comment: By that what i mean is after running that piece of code i am not getting a complete clean data. Still it's having some USER_ID which is VARCHAR not numerical.

Comment: Can you update your example code to include some lines that are not being cleaned properly by your solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isnumeric()` to `filter` the numeric values:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.USER_ID.str.isnumeric()]
```